# Smoke simulation in simulator_gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am making an smoke animation in blender 2.5 using its particle system.
Currently i am using ros electric on ubuntu 10.04 and simulator_gazebo stack.

My ist question is whether it is possible to import that animation correctly in simulator_gazebo? if not then migrating to gazebo_ros_pkgs with Hydro or Groovy will help me to achieve this objective? 
Second, Is there any other good approach to achieve this functionality for example simulating particles inside simulator_gazebo without using any other models(.dae, .stl) etc?
Last, I will prefer some solution sticking to same distro of ros but can migrate too.
Thanks alot.

(P.S detailed answer will be appreciated since my conceptual grasp on the topic is very less and limited)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3673/smoke-simulation-in-simulator_gazebo/) by [ZeeQ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/428/zeeq/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-19**:
You only want to visualize the smoke? You could try to animate it , check out this tutorial: `http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters` it currently only works with an older version of gazebo

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-19**:
You could try to write a Gui-Plugin (http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/plugins/system_gui_plugin) to make it work using an Ogre ParticlePlugin.
There is a smoke simulation in the Ogre/Samples https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/51da63f2a9cd/Samples/Smoke?at=v1-9

But this would only do a visualisation there would be no collisions with your robots.

I don't think you can easily port ParticleSystems from Blender to Gazebo, but I might be wrong in this point.

**Comment by [ZeeQ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/428/zeeq/) on 2013-07-19**:
@Andrei No visualization is less important in my case. I want something which reacts to Laser Range sensor and when density is decrease or increase difference could be seen in Laser readings. So visualization is not important even a set of particles just floating will do the trick without any smoke like look. question is how to simulate it? Thanks

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-19**:
Currently there is no particle simulation in Gazebo, you could make one by spawning multiple spheres and controlling them via plugins (computing forces between them etc), but that will take a lot of CPU time, and the simulation will get really slow. I am also currently having a project to integrate particles in Gazebo, but the project is not even close to being complete, (here are some videos: `http://vimeo.com/user16219305` ) there is no real interaction yet with the gazebo objects.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-19**:
Isn't there any option to add some noise to the scanner? And maybe then you could hack it to give an area where the laser will be noisy

**Comment by [ZeeQ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/428/zeeq/) on 2013-07-19**:
Thanks alot. That is very impressive work in video. So hopefully my last question what could be the smart way to spawn multiple spheres which are static not moving? no need of simulation and plugins. I can make an assumption that smoke is uniformly distributed at specific place in environment and is not evaporating any more? and i can experiment with increasing or decreasing the density of these spheres and check the laser range behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

You could create a world plugin which spawns the spheres. Here is a similar example of a plugin:
(don't forget to set them as static if you don't want them to move, that way it doesn't use as much CPU as well)

```
#include "gazebo/gazebo.hh"
#include "physics/physics.hh"
#include "common/Plugin.hh"
#include "transport/transport.hh"
#include <math.h>

namespace gazebo
{
  class FactoryLiquid : public WorldPlugin
  {
        public: virtual ~FactoryLiquid()
        {

        }
    public: void Load(physics::WorldPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
        math::Vector3 p3, init_pos;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////// SDF PARAMETERS

        ////////////// Get nr of spheres
        if (!_sdf->HasElement("nr_spheres"))
        {
          std::cout << "Missing parameter <nr_spheres> in FactoryLiquid, default to 0" << std::endl;
          nr_spheres = 0;
        }
        else nr_spheres = _sdf->GetElement("nr_spheres")->GetValueUInt();

        ////////////// Set up the initial position parameter
        if (!_sdf->HasElement("init_pos"))
        {
          std::cout << "Missing parameter <init_pos> in FactoryLiquid, default to 0 0 0" << std::endl;
          init_pos.x = 0.0;
          init_pos.y = 0.0;
          init_pos.z = 0.0;
        }
        else init_pos = _sdf->GetElement("init_pos")->GetValueVector3();
         
        // etc. other parameters from the world file

        /////// END SDF PARAMETERS
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////// START XML LIQUID
        xml << "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n";
        xml << "<sdf version='1.4'>\n";
        xml << "<model name='liquid_spheres'>\n";
        xml << "\t<static>false</static>\n";
        xml << "\t<pose>" << init_pos.x << " " << init_pos.y << " " << init_pos.z << " 0 0 0 </pose>\n";

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<nr_spheres; i++)
        {
                p3 = FactoryLiquid::part_position(i, radius, spawned, level);
                xml << "\t\t<link name='sphere_link_" << i << "'>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t<self_collide>true</self_collide>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t<pose>" << p3.x << " " << p3.y << " " << p3.z << " 0 0 0</pose>\n";

                xml << "\t\t\t<inertial>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<inertia>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<ixx>" << inertia << "</ixx>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<ixy>0</ixy>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<ixz>0</ixz>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<iyy>" << inertia << "</iyy>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<iyz>0</iyz>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<izz>" << inertia << "</izz>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t</inertia>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<mass>" << mass << "</mass>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t</inertial>\n";

                xml << "\t\t\t<collision name='collision_" << i << "'>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<geometry>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<sphere>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<radius>" << radius << "</radius>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</sphere>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t</geometry>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<surface>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<friction>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<ode>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<mu>" << mu << "</mu>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<mu2>" << mu2 << "</mu2>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<fdir1>0.0 0.0 0.0</fdir1>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<slip1>" << slip1 << "</slip1>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<slip2>" << slip2 << "</slip2>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t</ode>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</friction>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<bounce>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<restitution_coefficient>" << bounce << "</restitution_coefficient>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<threshold>10000.0</threshold>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</bounce>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<contact>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<ode>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<soft_cfm>" << cfm << "</soft_cfm>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<soft_erp>" << erp << "</soft_erp>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<kp>" << kp << "</kp>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<kd>" << kd << "</kd>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<max_vel>100.0</max_vel>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<min_depth>0.001</min_depth>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t</ode>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</contact>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t</surface>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t</collision>\n";

                xml << "\t\t\t<visual name='sphere_visual_" << i << "'>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<geometry>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<sphere>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<radius>" << radius << "</radius>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</sphere>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t</geometry>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t<material>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<script>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<name>Gazebo/Red</name>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</script>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t\t</material>\n";
                xml << "\t\t\t</visual>\n";
                xml << "\t\t</link>\n";
        }

                xml << "</model>\n";
                xml << "</gazebo>\n";

                /////////////////////////////////////////
        //std::cout << xml.str() << "\n";

        sdf::SDF sphereSDF;
        sphereSDF.SetFromString(xml.str());


        _parent->InsertModelSDF(sphereSDF);

    }
   
    // function to position the particles
    public: math::Vector3 part_position(int i, double radius, int& spawned, int& level)
    {
 
                return v3;
    }
};

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(FactoryLiquid)
}
```

This is how you add it to the world:

```
    ...
    <plugin name="factory_liquid" filename="libfactory_liquid.so">
            <init_pos>0.2 -0.0 1.0</init_pos>
            <nr_spheres>40</nr_spheres>
            <!-- other parameters -->
    </plugin>
    ...
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZeeQ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/428/zeeq/) on 2013-07-26**:
Thanks Andrei, I am using Simulator_gazebo in ROS electric under ubuntu 10.04 and i am unable to compile it using the method in this tutorial. http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro Any suggestions please? When i compile the example in the given tutorial it does not recognize gazebo headers files and other classes. Thanks

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-26**:
well you are using a pretty old version of gazebo which is deprecated, can't you install a newer version?